# C# ASP.net Populate GridView with ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, imagebutton

I`m pretty new to c# , asp.net and Visual Studio, my usual lineup is Java with Eclipse (and Captain Casa).

So my actual problem is the following.

```
           DataTable lowerTable = new DataTable();

        // create columns
        for (int i = 0; i < logic.gameSize; i++)
        {
            lowerTable.Columns.Add();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < logic.gameSize; j++)
        {
            // create a DataRow using .NewRow()
            DataRow row = lowerTable.NewRow();


            // iterate over all columns to fill the row
            for (int i = 0; i < logic.gameSize; i++)
            {
                ImageButton button = new ImageButton();
                button.ImageUrl = "";
                button.AlternateText = logic.getValue(logic.bord.getLowerBord()[j, i].getFigur()).ToString();

                row[i] = button;
            }

            // add the current row to the DataTable
            lowerTable.Rows.Add(row);
            LowerField.Controls.Add(new ImageButton());
            LowerField.DataSource = lowerTable;
            try
            {
                LowerField.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Im creating a DataTable to fill my GridView ... But the Result is not the expected Grid full of Buttons, but a Grid filled with the Text : System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.
I allready tried to use a globalized Button, but that didnt help either. 
Do i overlook a simple mechanic? I actually couldnt find anything fitting by Google, or at least nothing that fitted my actual needs.

Hope you might help
Thank you
Bienenwolf

Comment: You need to use an ASP.NET control such as `GridView` or `ListView` (or any of the numerous others). If you want to do it dynamically, [here's a link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AddDynamicallyControlstoGri-d74fe84f). Otherwise, it's as simple as setting up an `ItemTemplate` of some sort in your control's ASPX code [like this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb288031.aspx) - just change the template field to include an `ImageButton`.

Comment: Your first link was pretty usefull, thank you. How i now fixed it : Using the OnDataBound function to add a control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the buttons inside the grid view with template fields like this:

```
//Put the a key value in DataKeyNames so you can get it in case of editing
<asp:GridView ID="gdvValores" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  DataKeyNames="id">
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnEditar" CssClass="btnEditar" runat="server" OnClick="btnEditar_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="35px" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And in .cs

```
protected void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Get rowidex of gridview
    int linha = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow)(((System.Web.UI.Control)(sender)).BindingContainer)).RowIndex;
//Get the ID in case of editing a item
    ViewState["codigo"] = gdvValores.DataKeys[linha]["id"].ToString();    

}
```